# Relative Imports in Python 3.8.13 / PyCharm - sudden ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, path, package, pycharm, relative-import

I have the following simplified repo structure:

```
- project
  - src
    - config
      - config_new.py
    - util
      - util_new.py
    - app
      - app_new.py
```

The app_new.py module looks like the following (it is the core module to be executed via python app_new.py):

```
from project.src.config.config_new import ConfigClass
from project.src.util.util_new import UtilClass

def func1():
   ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   func1()
```

After my old repo had to be closed, I cloned the new repo version into my PyCharm project folder and associated my pre-existing virtual environment with the new repo. However, after cloning, the relative imports do suddenly not work anymore across the repo and the following error is thrown:

```
from project.config import config_new.py    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "config_new.py"
```

I have literally tried anything:

- Cleared PyCharm cache
- Checked interpreter paths
- Inputted **init**.py files into the root directory and all subdirectories
- Cloned the repo multiple times
- Marked all directories above as source directories
- Experimented with double dots on the relative imports to refer to top-level directories
- Checked this helpful thread and all related threads: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

As far as I have understood, when using a module with if **name** == "**main**":, the relative import is not considered to be in a package. However, I could use this exact setup before cloning the repo again and re-associating the existing virtual environment with it. Is there anything else I might have overlooked? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running from outside the `project` folder with `python project/src/app/app_new.py`?

Comment: I just tried it and the error persists unfortunately

Comment: `from project.config import config_new.py`  shouldn't this read from project.src.config? Are you running it in Pycharm? Can you post your run configuration?

Answer (score 1):

**You may be trying to import using the wrong path.**

If this:

```
- project
  - src
    - config
      - config_new.py
    - util
      - util_new.py
    - app
      - app_new.py
```

is your project structure, the path to the scripts shouldn't be `project.config.config_new.py` but `project.src.config.config_new.py`. Therefore you would need to change your import statements from `from project.config import config_new.py` to `from project.src.config import config_new.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply and I am sorry, I just posted an incomplete import statement here. It is now fixed.